# How to update map values x with y in Clojure?

Tags: dictionary, clojure, clojurescript

I am trying to make a function in Clojure that would take a map, x and y values as parameters and then go through all the elements in a map and potentially replace all x values (if any) with y.

```
(defn Change-x-to-y-in-map [map x y]; code here)
```

For example, if I would have a map like `{:a 1 :b 2 :c 1}` and I would call the function with parameters [map 1 "it works!"], the function should return the following map: `{:a "it works!" :b 2 :c "it works!}`.

So it would replace all keys with value 1 to keys with value "it works!".

Thank you already beforehand for your help!

Comment: That would require a linear search of the map, which isn't ideal. Having said that, this could be done trivially using `map` or `for`. Have you tried using either of those?

Comment: have a look at the `fmap` function, it does this: https://github.com/clojure/algo.generic/blob/aa028f7467d193a5cfad0626b324f4c682b91c15/src/main/clojure/clojure/algo/generic/functor.clj#L19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from [Stefan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49630771/1562315), we can modify the initial map instead of building a new one:

```
(defn update-v [m ov nv] 
  (reduce-kv (fn [acc k v] (if (= v ov) (assoc acc k nv) acc))
             m m))
```

And we can use a transient to make the modifications to:

```
(defn update-v [m ov nv] 
  (persistent!
    (reduce-kv (fn [acc k v] (if (= v ov) (assoc! acc k nv) acc))
             (transient m) m)))
```

These changes should (hmmmmmm) speed things up a little.

(I hereby put this code under Apache 2.0 license if you can't take it under the SO default CC-BY SA)

Comment: Looks good to me. Would you also put it under ASL? Otherwise OP can't use your extensions in non-CC code.

Comment: @StefanKamphausen Done.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this generically over any form with [`clojure.walk`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.walk-api.html) functions:

```
(defn replace-vals [m v r]
  (walk/postwalk
    (fn [e] (if (= e v) r e))
    m))

(replace-vals {:a 1 :b 2 :c 1} 1 "Hey!")
=> {:a "Hey!", :b 2, :c "Hey!"}

(replace-vals [1 2 3 4 1] 1 "Hey!")
=> ["Hey!" 2 3 4 "Hey!"]
```

This will also work for nested forms.

```
(replace-vals {:a 1 :b {:c 1 :d "Bye!"}} 1 "Hey!")
=> {:a "Hey!", :b {:c "Hey!", :d "Bye!"}}
```

If you want to only replace map *values* you could refactor to this:

```
(defn replace-map-vals [m v r]
  (walk/prewalk
    (fn [e] (if (and (map-entry? e) (= (val e) v))
              [(key e) r]
              e))
    m))

(replace-map-vals {1 "not replaced" :replaced 1} 1 "Hey!")
=> {1 "not replaced", :replaced "Hey!"})
```

Note this version uses `prewalk` due to [an issue with `postwalk` and map entries](https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-2031).

Comment: Interesting. Postwalk only looks at the values, not keys?

Comment: @johnbakers my original example looks at every value in the form, so keys would be included. Added another example using `prewalk` that only tries to replace map values.

Comment: But (fn [e] (if (= e v) r e)) if e is k/v pair, how can that be = to just the value v, which excludes the key?

Comment: In other words, why does your first version example on a map work as your example suggests? It has the same functionality as your second version, on maps, but I don't see how that can be.  Both versions are replacing values, not just the second version.

Comment: @johnbakers try using `prewalk-demo` or `postwalk-demo` on a form to see how it traverses. Yes, the function _will_ receive the entire map entry in one step, but it will also receive the individual key and value as it traverses.

Answer (score 2):

A reducible-friendly version would use `reduce-kv` directly:

```
(defn update-v [m ov nv] 
  (reduce-kv (fn [acc k v]
              (assoc acc k (if (= v ov) nv v)))
             {} m))
```

(update-v {:x 1 :y 2 :z 1} 1 "It Works!")
=> {:x "It Works!", :y 2, :z "It Works!"}

(I hereby put this code under Apache 2.0 license if you can't take it under the SO default CC-BY SA)

Comment: That is true. I wouldn't know any solution that does not iterate over the map, though.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to iterate through the keys and values of the map with `for` and use `into` to build up the new map:

```
(defn val-replace [m x y]
  (into {} (for [[k v] m]
             [k (if (= v x) y v)])))

> (val-replace {:x 1 :y 2 :z 1} 1 "It Works!")
{:x "It Works!", :y 2, :z "It Works!"}

> (val-replace1 {:a "" :b 4 :c ""} "" nil)
{:a nil, :b 4, :c nil}
```

Comment: Sorry!  Fixed.  Had the `x` instead of the `v` in the else clause of the if.

Answer (score 0):

Specter solution to boot:

```
(defn replace-vals [m v r] 
    (setval [MAP-VALS (partial = v)] r m))
```

Answer (score -2):

The function `map-vals` already exists [in the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).  It applies a function `tx-fn` to every value in the map, creating a new output map.  The unit tests show it in action:

```
  (let [map-123 {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}
        tx-fn   {1 101 2 202 3 303}]
    (is= (t/map-vals map-123 inc)   {:a   2, :b   3, :c   4})
    (is= (t/map-vals map-123 tx-fn) {:a 101, :b 202, :c 303}))
```

In the first case, the function `inc` is applied to each value in the input map (IM).

The 2nd example uses a "transformation map" as `tx-fn`, where each [k v] pair indicates the desired transformation from old to new values, respectivly, in IM.  Thus we see values in `map-123` changed as:

```
1 -> 101
2 -> 202 
3 -> 303
```

A sister function `map-keys` is also available:

```
(dotest
  (let [map-123 {1 :a 2 :b 3 :c}
        tx-fn   {1 101 2 202 3 303}]
    (is= (t/map-keys map-123 inc)   {  2 :a   3 :b   4 :c})
    (is= (t/map-keys map-123 tx-fn) {101 :a 202 :b 303 :c}))
```